# What is the right regex that matches one of the substrings at the end of the word in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I nedd the check whether the word ends with one of the   _LNG , _DBL   , _STR . My regex is

```
"_[(LNG|DBL|STR)]$"
```

but does work . Following must match but did'nt work. (I use java)

```
PARAM_LNG
```

I have tried following

```
"[(_LNG|_DBL|_STR)]$"
```

but it matchs with following although it has no underscore.

```
PARAMLNG
```

Can anyone show the right regex? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `[]`, that's a character class specification.

```
"_(LNG|DBL|STR)$"
```

Note that this will only match at the end of the string. Try:

```
"_(LNG|DBL|STR)\b"
```

to match any word ending with those suffixes inside a string.